# Wrong auth code using laravel and pusher when using a presence channel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I am creating a chat rooms functionality on my website. However, when the client sends an /broadcasting/auth request on the channel, the returned auth code is in incorrect format. Specifically, it adds a colon at the start. However, it only does that during production, not on local.

```
routes/channels.php

Broadcast::channel('Chat.{roomId}', function ($user, $roomId) {
  return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
});
[/broadcasting/auth response][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

i have actually same issue and finally solved by setting following envs

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxx
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap3
```